# Ruby on Rails single page application naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question related with Ruby on Rails naming convention.

I am trying to create a single page website. What is the best practice for naming single page application main controller in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: ApplicationController should do just fine.

Comment: Not clear as to what are you trying to ask , can you provide more details on what you are trying to get answers for

Comment: Refer this - http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7

Comment: @PhilVarg, so, I should just create a custom view and render it from ApplicationController?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder I have checked this page without finding an answer...

Comment: Create a home controller and then inherit it from application controller .

Comment: You will have a view folder named home and under that keep your home view related files , also do write the routes for home .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder, maybe it is a coincidence, but I am trying to create webpage just like yours (single page based). What kind of MVC architecture should I use? Do I need to create a `home_controller.erb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what best would be in your case

Create a home_controller and inherit it from Application controller , something like this

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

end
```

In the views part , create a different folder named home under views and list all the html.erb files you would need

Finally , the routes ....

If you need all the CRUD actions  ...mention this

```
resources :home
```

and that's it

Comment: This is best because your website is prone to expand, and if you put it all in ApplicationController you'd need to move it out again once you realise it's not going to be a single-page site any more.

Answer (score 1):

Well following rails and restful conventions, you should still be using route based mvc's when rendering views. But if you need a controller for your root or login, a session or application controller is common

Comment: I am creating single page website. With this single page thing, I messed up, how to design architecture? Do I need to create something like `home_controller.rb`? If so, is it a good name `home_controller` for it? Can I render a `application.html.erb` from `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: If you're building a single page app, then you're using ajax to render new 'pages'. These requests should still be hitting restful controllers rendering partials with layout false. Application.HTML.erb is your layout, not a view your controller renders. Your application controller really only renders an index, which is your root route (though If you have user sign in, a common structure is to have a session controller handle the root in addition to user sign in/out depending on your needs)